anorexiant αMSH does the question better fit Medical Sciences or Psychology and Neuroscience
A couple of months ago I had a class in Nutritional Genomics (Biology II-Genetics, First Year Medicine).
I heard that people with a mutation in MC4R overeat.
So I took my time and started researching why that is so.
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8990120/
My research journey first took me to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2748318/
Agouti related protein and then back to MC4R since agouti seems to be an antagonist to αMSH binding to MC4R.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5999398/
So aMSH binding to MC4R has been observed to have anorexiant effects.
I asked https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/30416/anorexiant-%ce%b1msh
In Psychology&Neuroscience but it only has 20 views in more than 50 days.
The question is whether

How does αMSH binding to MC4R create a feeling of satiety (anorexiant
effects in general)?
Rewording the question what are the changes in the neuron's membrane
after αMSH binds to the receptor or inside the cell itself how does
this translate to a anorexiant effects?

is a better fit for Medical Sciences rather that Psychology and Neuroscience?
The question has little to do with medical practice. I am asking about a phenomenon and I want it explained. I thought it is better for Neuroscience since there is a specific Stack Exchange for that. The question is specifically about Cell Neurobiology.
I am entirely open to migration. I am welcoming any migration or edits.
Should the question be migrated I am thinking of the tags
Nutrition
Brain
Neurology
Neuroscience
Psychiatry

I think it's more appropriate in P&N where it is. I would attribute the low interest to how niche a question it is, and I don't think it would be better on MedSci. If you want to get it bumped back up to the top of the list and perhaps get more eyes on it, edit and add some additional research you've found.

@CareyGregory How much of a niche can it be when it is motivated by a first year lecture (most people hearing it where 18 years old)? Isn't there something to fix like the tags; is the question, wording and all, fine as it is?

It can be plenty niche even if 18 year olds were hearing it. You're asking about cellular bindings and peptides and such. That right there makes it niche. I don't see anything about the question that could obviously be improved to gain readership. Just bumping it up will do that.

@CareyGregory Out of 13 weeks (with 6 hours of lectures per week) in Cell Biology-Biology I (in the first semester many where still 17) I am pretty sure much more than a couple were dedicated to Cell Membrane (including the function of Protein in Membranes), Protein Folding, Cell Signaling. I thought that Cellular Bindings, Peptides and such were pretty basic.

Yes, but those are very low-level topics that would arguably be more appropriate in Biology.SE (notice which class you learned about them in). P&N and MedSci tend to be populated by people with interests in higher-level topics..

@CareyGregory Knowing the categories of proteins in the cell membrane and their functions. And knowing the importance of cell signaling was the topic I learned in the class. I think that the specific molecular pathway of αMSH binding to MC4R, what happens to the Neuron as a Cell and the Brain as a Whole (when aMSH binds to MC4R ins neurons) and the abstraction needed to answer how does this translate to anorexiant effects make the question not that low-level. Even the professors replied they don't know when I asked them on the next day.

Okay, whatever. Next time you visit your doctor ask them about this and see what they know and how much they care.

@CareyGregory If they don't know that is a sign that it is not so low level. I will certainly ask my neurophysiology, neurochemistry, neuropsychology, neuroscience professors but not my neurologist I go for my epilepsy. A neurologist is not at the level of professors (probably also neurologists but they also have Master's, PhDs, fellowships not just their residence). I don't see much difference between my question and this one https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73866/why-cant-we-kill-ourselves-by-holding-our-breath

@GeorgeNtoulos If you visit a mechanic, you'd expect them to be able to diagnose problems with a machine (say, an automobile), identify any parts that need replacing, and do the replacement. All of the operation of the machine depends on physics, but just because this is low level it does not mean that you expect the mechanic to be an expert in the intricacies of particle physics and quantum mechanics - they don't need those things to be a good mechanic. Similarly a physician does not need an in depth understanding of everything in biology.

@GeorgeNtoulos If you would ask your professors but not your doctor then why are you considering moving the question to a place more likely to be populated by doctors than professors? As I suggested before, moving it to Biology.SE might be the better place for it.

@CareyGregory I will ask if it is a better fit to Biology.SE but it can't be migrated now since I have reached the question limit (in the main site). I don't understand what criteria does the system have to flag a question as poorly received. I can't understand how the last question was poorly received. https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/114492/central-diabetes-insipidus-and-antidiuretic-hormone it seems I wasted my last question and now I have to wait for a while. That question about antidiuretic hormone I believe was much better fit for Biology. Before I asked I was ok but after not

@GeorgeNtoulos That question has an upvote of +4 so I don't understand how anyone thought it was poorly received. You can either just post this same meta question in Biology meta or delete the question from P&N and copy/paste it as a new question in Biology. I would probably delete it from P&N and open it as a new question in Biology. Don't cross-post or you risk having both of them closed.

@CareyGregory The system counts it towards the limit. While I could ask a question before I asked (the last one probably) I could no longer ask one after. I had no changes to my other questions since I asked this one. I am going to post the same question in Biology meta after a couple of months so they can migrate the question.
